# How to define variable in jison/bison

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, jison

I need to store data in my jison variable and then retrieve the stored value and perform a simple arithmetic operation. I tried conditional operation and expression are working fine, but after I added a variable rule I got an error.

My input is:

> myvar1=3 myvar2=4 then myvar1+myvar2

And I get this error:

```
Parse error on line 1:
myvar=4
-----^
Expecting '=', 'EOF', '+', '-', '*', '/', '^', '<', '>', '==', '!=', '=<', '>=', got 'INVALID'
```

Here is my jison code:

```
/* description: Parses end executes mathematical expressions. */
/* lexical grammar */

%{

var sym={};
%}
%lex
%%

\s+                   /* skip whitespace */
[0-9]+("."[0-9]+)?\b  return 'NUMBER'
[a-zA-Z]+\b           return 'VARIABLE'
"*"                   return '*'
"/"                   return '/'
"-"                   return '-'
"+"                   return '+'
"^"                   return '^'
"("                   return '('
")"                   return ')'
"PI"                  return 'PI'
"E"                   return 'E'
"<"                    return "<"
"=<"                    return "=<"
">="                    return ">="
">"                    return ">"
"=="                    return "=="
"!="                    return "!="
"IF"                   return "IF"
"THEN"                   return "THEN"
"ELSE"                   return "ELSE"
<<EOF>>               return 'EOF'

.                     return 'INVALID'

/lex

/* operator associations and precedence */
%left '<' '>' '==' '!='  '>=' '=<' '&&'
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/'
%left '^'
%left UMINUS

%start statement

%% /* language grammar */

statement
        : expressions
        | VARIABLE '=' expressions{ sym[$1]=$3}
;

expressions
    : e EOF
        {return $1;}
    ;

e
:VARIABLE
{ $$=sym[$1]=$3}
    | e '+' e
        {$$ = $1+$3;}

    | e '-' e
        {
$$ =function(){

return $1-$3;
}($1,$3)}
    | e '*' e
        {$$ = $1*$3;}
    | e '/' e
        {$$ = $1/$3;}
    | e '^' e
        {$$ = Math.pow($1, $3);}
    | '-' e %prec UMINUS
        {$$ = -$2;}
    | '(' e ')'
        {$$ = $2;}
    | NUMBER
        {$$ = Number(yytext);}
    | E
        {$$ = Math.E;}
    | PI
        {$$ = Math.PI;}
| e '<' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1<$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}
| e '>' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1>$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}

| e '==' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1==$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}
| e '!=' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1!=$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}
| e '=<' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1==$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}
| e '>=' e
{
$$=function(){
return $1>=$3?true:false;
}($1,$3)
}

|'IF''('e')''THEN''('e')''ELSE''('e')' 
{
$$= $3?$7:$11;
}
   ;
```

Comment: I tried to clean up your formatting a bit. Please double check it. Note that the error message mentions a variable that doesn't appear in your input. Please [edit] your question and fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lexer never produces any `=` tokens. If you look at your list of token rules, the only one that would match a single `=` is `.`, which produces an `INVALID` token.

So since the rule `VARIABLE '=' expressions` expects a `=` token, the match fails and you get the syntax error telling you that (among other things) a `=` would have been expected.

Once you've fixed that, another issue will be that your `expressions` rule (which seems to be misnamed as it only seems to match a single expression) expects an `EOF` at the end, so your input file would have to end after the first assignment. In fact, multiple assignments wouldn't be supported anyway because you only ever match a single statement. So to fix this, you should remove the `EOF` from your `expressions` rule and instead add a rule that matches multiple statements followed by the end of file (if you need to have an EOF token at all) and then make that rule your starting rule.

Comment: i still get confuse about parser because of iam new to jison.can u show with simple example for this problem?